# What's the difference between delete (ptr->next) and delete q (q=ptr->next)?

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

the code is for linkList, I want to free the memory of The deleted Node, but one approach causes memory leak. What is the difference of two ways?

```
bool LinkList::deleteElement(int i, EleMentType &e) {
    int j = 0;
    List Ptr = linkList;
    while (Ptr->Next && j < i - 1) {
        Ptr = Ptr->Next;
        j++;
    }

    if (!Ptr->Next || j > i - 1) {
        std::cout << "Failed to delete an element\n";
        return false;
    }

    // Memory Leak
    // Ptr->Next = Ptr->Next->Next;
    // e = Ptr->Next->Data;
    // delete Ptr->Next;

    /* without Memory Leak */
    List q = Ptr->Next;
    Ptr->Next = q->Next;
    e = q->Data;
    delete q;

    return true;
}
```

Comment: This code is awful. It looks like you've hidden a pointer behind a `typedef` (`List`). :-(

Comment: What's the difference between `int x = 1; x = x + 1; printf("%d\n", x);` and `int x = 1; int q = x; x = q + 1; printf("%d\n", q);`?

Answer (score 1):

The difference is you are not deleting the same node:

```
Ptr->Next = Ptr->Next->Next;  // modifies Ptr->Next, original value is lost
e = Ptr->Next->Data;          // Ptr->Next may be null, causing undefined behavior
delete Ptr->Next;             // deleting a node that is still pointed to by the list, potential future undefined behavior.
```

Note that is is considered bad style to hide pointers behind typedefs.

Note also that you cannot delete the first node (at offset `0`) with this function although it would be easy to write code that modifies `linkList` directly for this purpose.